# High end graphics card gives low GPU clock speed (and terrible performance) in games, but has high GPU clock speed in render tests

Tags: performance, gpu

I'm getting really terrible framerates in really old games with an [AMD R9 390 (8GB)](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/r9)

*Counter Strike Source* runs at 50-60 frames per second, and it’s the same regardless of quality settings or resolution. *World of Warcraft* runs at 10-70 frames per second depending on settings and what is happening around me, safe to say the average is in the low teens unless I’m looking directly at a wall or something.

Running GPU-Z, I find that these games do NOT kick the GPU Core clockspeed above 400MHz, despite GPU-Z's very own “test” being able to push it up to 1000MHz+.

This has been a problem ever since I upgraded video cards; prior to this, *Counter Strike Source* ran at 200+ FPS in highest quality settings and *World of Warcraft* ran at sustained 40-50 FPS with very high settings.

System Specs:

- **CPU:** AMD Phenom II x6 1100T @ 3.3GHZ
- **Logic Board:** ASUSTeK M4A89GTD-PRO/USB3
- **RAM**: Corsair 16GB low latency (was top of the line RAM when the 1100T was a top end CPU)
- **Video Card:** AMD Radeon R9 390 with 8GB v-RAM
- **OS:** Windows 10 x64

I would normally be worried about the age of the CPU, RAM, and Motherboard, but as I mentioned earlier, they were more than capable of running these games with an older discrete video card (I would try putting that one back in for point of reference, but the reason I got a new one in the first place is due to the untimely death of the original card).

My question is, how can I go about diagnosing the source of the problem and correcting it? I believe there is something wrong with my setup/configuration, because for whatever reason running games does not kick the GPU into gear, but the built-in GPU-Z render test is able to kick things up.

---

**Update --** after some more searching, I've seen some people suspect a PSU problem with symptoms similar to mine. I've tested and GPU-Z is reporting 11.50v on the 12v power rail; with occasional dips to 11.38v and peeking out at 11.63v; average is 11.50v. I will post the exact PSU specs when I can crack the case and get them; though it is a decent Thermaltake unit that is about two years old. Could this be my problem?

Comment: What about your motherboard?

Comment: @TimmyJim I've updated the question with the motherboard information.

Comment: Check for any catalyst settings that refer power saving etc, set them to Max performance. Also, look for and disable any adaptive vsync settings.

Comment: p.s. I know you said tyou had better results, but WOW and Source are known to be CPU bound, and you description sounds like a CPU-bound process.

Comment: @Yorik CPU usage shows very low running CSS and shows 30-50% when running WOW. Possibly due to the number of cores and lack of parallelization that can be achieved?